# Unable to choose top_n(100)

Tags: r

I need to choose the top 100 rows in descending order
Original Table

```
route   member_casual  n
A       member         5 
A       casual        10
B       member        21
B       casual         9
C       member        30 
C       casual        5
```

Required Table

```
route  member_casual n
C      member        30
B      member        21
A      member         5
A      casual        10   
B      casual         9
C      casual         5
```

code that I have already tried:

```
df %>% group_by(route,member_casual) %>% count() %>% top_n(100)
df %>% group_by(route,member_casual) %>% count() %>% top_n(100, wt = "n")
```

**The end goal is to make a geom_col to compare top 100 or 10 common routes between members and casual riders, with "n" on the x axis and "route" on y axis.**

Comment: Your test case doesn't require any filtering of your input data to produce your desired output, so it is not clear whether you want the top 100 `n`s *within* each value of `member_category` or the top 100 `n`s *across* both values of `member_category`.  You also have typos in your code attempts.  `df <- group_by...` should be `df <- df %>% group_by...` in both cases.  Welcome to SO all the same.

Comment: @Limey, thanks for pointing out the typos, they have been fixed. I am working with a dataset with 2,896,300 observations (rows). I want the common top_n(100) routes that are common to both members and casual riders.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `.by_group` to `TRUE`:

```
dat <- structure(list(route = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), member_casual = c("member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual"), n = c(5L, 
10L, 21L, 9L, 30L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

dat |> group_by(member_casual)|> 
  arrange(desc(n), .by_group = TRUE) |> 
  arrange(desc(member_casual))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   member_casual [2]
#  route member_casual     n
#  <chr> <chr>         <int>
#1 C     member           30
#2 B     member           21
#3 A     member            5
#4 A     casual           10
#5 B     casual            9
#6 C     casual            5
```

Then, you can select top n from the result:

```
dat |> 
  group_by(member_casual)|> 
  arrange(desc(n), .by_group = TRUE) |> 
  arrange(desc(member_casual)) |> top_n(2)

Selecting by n
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   member_casual [2]
  route member_casual     n
  <chr> <chr>         <int>
1 C     member           30
2 B     member           21
3 A     casual           10
4 B     casual            9
```

Note that `top_n()` has  been superseded in favour of slice_min()/slice_max(), as @Limey has kindly pointed out in the comment. Hence, it's recommended to use `slice_max()` in this case.

Comment: Though you should be aware that `top_n` has been supseseded by `slice_max`.